# How to submit my livecycle pdf form and store on my webserver?

Tags: pdf-generation, livecycle

I have not used livecycle before. There are overloads of info on this topic, but I can't find one page or example that explains how to correctly and simply, submit my filled out form to a directory on my webserver.

I have my pdf form created in livecycle ES2. I found good info in many forums, blogs etc and from adobe. But am I missing something thats needed to make this work? (that needs to be installed on the server?). I was under the impression my form could be filled out and submitted/saved to a directory from my site visitors without the use of anything installed on the server. I just want whatever the user fills out in the pdf to be saved to that pdf and saved to the server.

This link was helpful: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/332/332289.html

but I still am doing something wrong.

> Generic buttons
>
> You can set a generic button to be a submit button in the Object >
>   Field palette. Once you set the button as a submit button, a Submit
>   tab is available in the Object palette. You can choose the following
>   formats:

from that info provided - this is the solution I want :

> -- PDF: Submits a package containing an embedded PDF file. Choose this format if the form contains a signature field, or if a copy of the
>   form together with its data needs to be saved by Adobe LiveCycle Forms
>   or submitted to some other kind of target server. Do not choose this
>   option if the form initiates server-side processing, if Adobe
>   LiveCycle Forms will be used to render HTML or dynamic forms at run
>   time, or if the form is a PDF form that will be filled in Adobe Reader
>   without the use of Adobe LiveCycle Reader Extensions.

I read additional notes that I need to enable the usage rights which I tried by saving the form from LiveCycle, opening in ACROBAT X PRO and :

> extending the rights to the reader, there is no Advanced selection
>   under tools.
>
> In Adobe Pro X, to get the pdf fillable emailed back to you you must
>   save the file with the rights extended, and this is found in
>   File>>Save As>>Reader Extended PDF, and select “Enable Additional
>   Features.
>
> It will allow the receiver to fill and email or fill and save and
>   attach to and e-mail.

Has anyone had success with this? and know how to make it work? I created the generic button, edit properties, chose PDF and assigned a URL (the directory to store the saved files) ....what part am I missing?

Last but need least I read other info that said I need a servlet to save...??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a pdf in pdf designer, place a button. On the button click you can call the webservice as the code below

```
var cURL = <url to your webservice>; 
SOAP.wireDump = false;
var service = SOAP.connect(cURL);
var Input = {'<give the input to your webservice here>'};
var result = service.YourWebMethod(Input);
```

After dat save the form as Dynamic Xml Form.
the importent part is, you have to 'reader extend' the pdf you have created.